# Error deploying to Elastic Beanstalk: chown /var/app/staging/bin/python: no such file or directory

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my app to Elastic Beanstalk however the CLI keeps returning the following error when I run 'eb deploy'. I am puzzled because my app is running fine locally.

What does the error mean and how can I resolve it? I have been trying to find answers for hours with no luck. I am following the AWS Django deployment guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

error

```
2021/03/15 22:49:08.925837 [INFO] Executing instruction: StageApplication
2021/03/15 22:49:09.877646 [INFO] extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/
2021/03/15 22:49:09.877695 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /var/app/staging/
2021/03/15 22:49:18.870026 [INFO] finished extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/ successfully
2021/03/15 22:49:18.872859 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [StageApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: chown /var/app/staging/bin/python: no such file or directory
```

.ebextensions/django.config

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: myapp.wsgi:application
```

.ebextensions/01_packages.config

```
packages:
    yum:
        MySQL-python: []
```

Comment: The error means that `/var/app/staging/bin/python` does not exist, which is correct. This is wrong path for python. Do you have any ebextentions or deployment hooks that would try to use such path?

Comment: I have just updated the question with my config files. I just have a config file to install mysql-python using yum.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by installing MariaDb  instead of MYSQL since MariaDb comes with MYSQL installed.

```
packages:
    yum:
        mariadb-devel: []
```